# result in group between two non capture groups

Tags: python, regex-group

Im' trying to catch  pattern between two non capture groups in main group.
How can i make it ?

here it is part of my regex :
(?P(?:Alias\s+?name.).*?(?:\n))

part  of my text :
Alias name: Company root ca\n

correct output :
Company root ca

So who can explain me why it not working?

p.s essential condition for me  it use re.compile with re.S . Little bit  code to show :

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?P<alias>(?:Alias name).*?)(?:\n).*?'
                   r'(?P<entry>(?:Entry type).*?)(?:\n).*?'
                   r'(?P<Owner>(?:Owner).*?)(?:\n).*?'
                   r'(?P<Valid>(?:Valid from).*?[A-Z]{3}\s+?\d+).*?'
                   r'(?P<untin>(?:until).*?[A-Z]{3}\s+?\d+)', re.S)
for k in regex.finditer(text):
    f = k.groupdict()
    f['TimeStamp'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    f[jksfile] = jksfile
    print(f)  # eventually it will be dictionary
```

full regex example : https://regex101.com/r/IGjPaE/2

Guys, any help.....

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
st = 'Alias name: Company root ca\n'
f = re.findall(':(.*)',st)
```

The above code will work fine, no need to complicate.
Edit : You only need the expression `':(.*)'` for the data you need in the given string, if there are multiple similar data cases, you can use some kind of a nested `re` `search`, first extract the main string, and then the more specific one

Comment: in this case, I will choose matches that will be redundant

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
import re

t = "Alias name: Company root ca\n"

print(re.findall('(?<=Alias name: ).*',t))
```

Output:

```
Company root ca
```

Comment: Thanks  it work's  but only one string . how  i can modificate all this strings  ? 
`(r'(?P<alias>(?:Alias name).*?)(?:\n).*?'
 r'(?P<entry>(?:Entry type).*?)(?:\n).*?'
 r'(?P<Owner>(?:Owner).*?)(?:\n).*?'
 r'(?P<Valid>(?:Valid from).*?[A-Z]{3}\s+?\d+).*?'
 r'(?P<untin>(?:until).*?[A-Z]{3}\s+?\d+)', re.S)`

Comment: you mean `re.sub`?